# How to write such `y` into a `.csv` file (one column is `ID` and one column is our predict labeled `y`)?

Tags: python, csv

I have a label prediction of the testing data set `y`. It is an array of `0` and `1`. I also transfer it into a `20000` by `1` array as a label.

```
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
y_pred = (y_pred > 0.5)
y_pred=y_pred.astype(int)
y_pred1=np.reshape(y_pred, (20000,1))
```

```
print(y_pred1)
print(y_pred1.shape)
[[1 1 1 ... 0 0 0]]
(1, 20000)
```

I want to write such `y` into a `.csv` file (one column is `ID` and one column is our predict labeled `y`). I saw the following code:

```
result = pd.DataFrame({'Id':test['Id'].values, 'Default':y_pred.astype(np.int32)})
result.to_csv("1.csv", index=False)
result.head(10)
```

But there is an error report: `ValueError: Data must be 1-dimensional`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
result = pd.DataFrame({'Id':test['Id'].values, 'Default':y_pred.astype(np.int32)[0]})
```

The values are probably inside a one element list.

Comment: There is still the same error: 'ValueError: Data must be 1-dimensional'.

Comment: My `y_pred' is quite like an array but not a matrix...